# Permission denied error when using Twig after replacing a "vendor" directory

Tags: php, linux, symfony, twig

I am getting a permission denied error when using Twig.  This started to occur after I replaced a "vendor" directory with a back up.

```
Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream:
Permission denied in /var/www/html/myapp/http/lib.php on line 10

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php'
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
/var/www/html/myapp/http/lib.php on line 10
```

Line 10 is:

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
```

I am guessing this a folder permission problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed "folder access" to "access files" under the group options for the folder and then applied the permissions to the enclosed files.